# Wordpress: "Fatal error: Allowed memory size..." anytime I try to register and enqueue script in functions.php file

Tags: php, wordpress

Every time I try to register and enqueue script in my function.php file I get the error

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 261904 bytes) in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\namewebsite\wp-includes\class.wp-dependencies.php
>   on line 178

here is the code used in my functions.php file

```
function load_external_js() { // load external file  
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('hash-change', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.hashchange.event.plugin.js', array('hash-change'), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script('hash-change');
    wp_register_script('ajax-theme', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax-implementation.js', array('ajax-theme'), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax-theme');
}  
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_external_js');
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I forgot to say: I'm working on local machine

Comment: Hi, comment these two line and check wp_enqueue_script('hash-change'); and wp_enqueue_script('ajax-theme'); and after that if it is not working plese let me know.

Comment: @TheClouds I did it and it works but then I have not those two scripts among my resources in the website

Answer (score 4):

You are requiring scripts as dependencies of themselves:

`wp_register_script('hash-change', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.hashchange.event.plugin.js', array('hash-change'), '', true );
wp_enqueue_script('hash-change');`

change your call to wp_register_script to

`wp_register_script('hash-change', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.hashchange.event.plugin.js');`

Or, if you're really meaning to require another script as a dependency, register that script and reuire it by the handle you give it.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have access to your PHP.ini file, change the line in PHP.ini
   If your line shows 32M try 64M. If your line shows 64M try 128M
   `memory_limit = 64M` ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (32MB)
2. If you don't have access to `PHP.ini` try adding this to an `.htaccess` file:
   php_value memory_limit 64M
3. Try adding this line to your wp-config.php file:
   Increasing memory allocated to PHP
   `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');`
4. Talk to your host.

Found in: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-6#post-1017842

Comment: I'm working in local, so I don't need to talk to my host ;) Anyway, in php.ini the memory limit is already to 128M