# Error in WordPress while moving site to new Domain

Tags: php, wordpress

I was trying to move my WordPress site to a new Domain. However When I imported my content I got the below error Message:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted 
(tried to allocate 2123623   bytes) in 
/home2/username/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 122
```

Could any one of you please help me to fix this?

Comment: Edit your wp-settings.php define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '32M'); Change 32M to 64M will fix the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you have access to your PHP.ini file, change the line in PHP.ini
   If your line shows 32M try 64M. If your line shows 64M try 128M
   `memory_limit = 64M` ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (32MB)
2. If you don't have access to `PHP.ini` try adding this to an `.htaccess` file:
   `php_value memory_limit 64M`
3. Try adding this line to your wp-config.php file:
   Increasing memory allocated to PHP
   `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');`
4. Talk to your host.

Same question is also answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20540302/wordpress-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-anytime-i-try-to-register-and-e/20540374#20540374).

Found in: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-6#post-1017842

Answer (score 1):

By default memory_limit is `64M`. Add this line in `.htaccess` file.

```
php_value memory_limit 64M
```